# Open a new view controller on true iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm learning iOS programming right now and I started off building an app. So right now I'm working on registering a user which sends the details of the user to a server and then responds with a json array. The result can be true or false. Now what I want to do is if the result is true, open up a new view controller. I searched online and on stackoverflow and I did this

```
if([operation boolValue] == 0){
        NSLog(@"Account Registered: %s","Yes");
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:MainViewController animated:YES];


    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Account Registered: %s","No");
    }
```

But I get a "Use undeclared notifier" error and when I import the Main Controller I get a "unexpected interface name"

Aso with segues I don't think I can get it to work because the result could be true or false. Anyway, it would be great if someone could show me how to get this working.

ERROR:
"Use of undeclared identifier 'MainViewController'; Did you mean 'UIViewController?'"

Comment: Please show us exact error.

Comment: Do you have a variable named "MainViewController"?  I didn't think so.

Comment: Yes I do. It's a view controller declared in the storyboard.

Comment: You have a *varible* named "MainViewController"?  Show us how it's declared.

Comment: Oh in that way. No I didn't have it declared in the RegisterViewController but I think I needed to declare it as such MainViewController* controller = [[MainViewController alloc] init];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MainViewController is just a class name, you need to initialise the MainViewController:

```
MainViewController* controller = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

You may want to init the controller from the storyboard or a nib file.
You also need to make sure that the current ViewController has a NavigationController as it's parent.

Comment: Thanks @rogchap it worked. Now how would I do it without an embedded navigation controller because come to think of it a user should be able to go back after registering.

Comment: You need to have a read of the anatomy of a view controller: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html It all depends on the type of application you want to create to how you would push a new view.

Comment: You also may want to take a closer look at using storyboard segues to lay this out.